# Converting a list to dataframe in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, type-conversion

I currently have the following list:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.09920334

[[2]]
[1] 0.3003934 0.3201436 0.6357888 2.1023853 2.3922174

[[3]]
[1] 1.228495 1.828797 2.419319 

[[4]]
[1] 3.561023 3.626451
```

The assignment is simulating a cable car that picks up passengers at two different points. I've created a list that represents how many people it picks up based on when they arrived at the queue for the cable car.

The function itself randomly generates people arriving at different points of time, so amount of elements (passengers) in each list often are different, so I would like general code to arrange this list into something like this:

```
Nr. Passenger Arrival
1   0.09920334
2   0.3003934 
2   0.3201436 
2   0.6357888 
2   2.1023853 
2   2.3922174
3   1.228495 
3   1.828797 
3   2.419319 
4   3.561023 
4   3.626451
```

With Nr. being the ride that each passenger was on.

Thanks for the help, I hope the problem is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this easily in `base R`.  If 'lst' is the `list` object then set the names of the `list` elements with `sequence` of length, `stack` it to a 2 column `data.frame` and change the column names with `setNames`

```
setNames(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)))[2:1], c("Nr.", "PassengerArrival"))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! Works perfectly, now I just need to understand it :D